# Should I connect my foundation's weeping tile to neighborhood storm water drains?

Tags: basement, foundation, sump-pump, drains, weeping-tile

My house sits at the bottom of a hill, and the water table gets high when snow melts and during heavy rains. We have 2 sump pits that fill quickly during these times, and the sump pumps are on and off regularly. We've done work to control surface water, but it's clear the water table is just high around our house at times.

I want to improve the water drainage around our home's foundation so we are less reliant on our sump pumps, both bc if the risk of them failing and our basement flooding, and also I just don't like the noise they make.

A few years ago, a new storm water system was installed in our neighbourhood, with a catch basin in our neighbour's yard. We had a family friend who is an engineer come by and do some measurements and found that we have enough slope from the base of our sump pits to the nearby catch basin that we could theoretically have a gravity drain set up.

I am considering connecting our home's weeping tile to the storm drains, so we have a gravity drain situation to move water away from our foundation.

Here are some pros/cons I'm thinking of.

Pros of connecting to storm drain:

- reduce/eliminate sump pump activity
- reduce basement flooding risk
- Low risk of back flow from overwhelmed storm drains (we live across the road from a cliff, and the storm drain empties on the cliff down into the lake)
- we have very old weeping tile, original to the house built in the 60's, made of clay tiles. It has failed in one section already and was replaced by the previous owner. It is likely blocked in other areas- my evidence for this is that when our sump pits drain, they do not drain the weeping tile entirely, just whatever water is in the sump pit and then it slowly fills back up.
- we need to excavate to install a new driveway in the next year or two, so we could do this all at once

Cons:

- If we need to install new weeping tile around the whole house for this to work, it would be very expensive.
- We have clay soil, which can block new weeping tile. I've seen some estimates say this can happen within 10 years, so that's a big risk.
- We have limestone bedrock very close under our soil. Our house is built on top of the bedrock. It's possible that we'd hit limestone as we try to connect to the catch basin, which adds more $$ to our total.
- This will be expensive.
- It would be cheaper to buy two water powered backup pumps instead, but that doesn't eliminate the noise pollution, and if our weeping tile decides to block/stop working, we might need to replace it anyways.

My questions:

- Are there any other pro/cons I am not thinking of?
- What is the chance that this project just balloons in cost and scope?
- What is the chance that we do all this work, and my sump pumps are still active?
- Am I crazy for even considering this? Do people just happily live with very busy sump pumps? It's new for me, and just feels like a risky system to rely on.

Comment: It will depend on how much you would need to excavate the bedrock, but it can be done.  I would be more worried about the cliff, cray/limestone, and high water table.  Depending on the location, it seems not lifetime stable place to be, but might be where you are.

Comment: A) I'm sure someone somewhere has tried it. How will knowing that help? B) if you'll take the [tour] and read up on [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), you'll see that "love to year your stories" isn't a good question fit for here. We can't help you determine if it's "worth it", because we don't know what value you put on all the different variable involved. If you [edit] to ask about pros/cons, then you'll get some good lists and _you_ can decide if it's "worth it"...

Comment: Also, with the local authorities allow you to tap directly into the side of their catch basin? I've discovered that in our town, our inspector not only said it was OK, but actively encouraged it. That may not be the case in all municipalities.

Comment: Any chance you can regrade so that the area around your house drains to the neighbor's catch basin (obviously with their permission)?

Comment: Unfortunately I think it's underground water from uphill that we are dealing with. But I know surface water can get down there and cause problems so I am simultaneously regrading around the house, and also managing water flowing through the back of our yard to see if that has any impact.

Answer (score 0):

A non-pumped drain is always preferable to a pumped drain if possible to install. *Whether you find that cost-effective is between you and your local costs, not something anyone else can really help you with.*

I would suggest that there's probably a middle ground of simply putting the drain to the storm-water drain in from the catch basin to the house without bothering to re-do do the entire system around the house, as that's evidently working, since water gets to the sumps. It could be jetted out when you have a corner or edge exposed to put the new drain in, without replacing the whole thing. Indeed, if you can punch a pipe from the sump(s) to the stormwater drain, that should make your sump pumps obsolete.

Limestone is far from impassable as rock that might be in the way goes. It's pretty easy to cut with a suitable hunk of equipment, blasting should not be required.

Comment: My neighbours dug out their basement in granite rock.  I would have just laid a stab on top instead of going eight feet down in hard rock.

Comment: Limestone ain't granite. Cuts like buttah, comparatively. How's their radon situation, or didn't they check? ;^) Hmm, I wonder how much 4" trench a gallon of cheap acid would clear in limestone...

Comment: He is a chemical engineer, so I imagine they checked/have the radon situation covered.  It did take them a few weeks to chisel/jack hammer(big excavator) the basement out.